# Same table for two many to many relationships with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying create two many to many relationships in Entity Framework using the same intermediate table.

Is possible use the same table for two relationship using Entity Framework?

```
public class Alert
{
    public Alert()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<SXUser>();
        Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
    }

    public Guid AlertId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SXUser> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class SXUser
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In database I have:

[image: Database]

How configure the relationship in mapping?
I tried:

```
public class AlertMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Alert>
{
    public AlertMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.AlertId);

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.AlertId).IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(t => t.Code).IsRequired()
            .HasColumnAnnotation(
                IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
                new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("AK_Alert", 1) { IsUnique = true })
            );

        Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired();


        // Relationships
        HasMany(t => t.Users).WithMany().Map(t=>t.ToTable("AlertRecipient").MapLeftKey("AlertId").MapRightKey("UserId"));
        HasMany(t => t.Groups).WithMany().Map(t => t.ToTable("AlertRecipient").MapLeftKey("AlertId").MapRightKey("GroupId"));
    }
}
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a middle table you can only define an ICollection of that middle table in every Alert/User. So for example User:

```
virtual ICollection<AlertRecipient> {get; set;}
```

for Alertrecipient:

```
virtual Alert {get; set;}
virtual User {get; set;}
```

Also add the ID's of `Alert` and `User` in your `Alertrecipient` model. 
In fluent API your mapping for `Alertrecipient` will look something like this:

```
ModelBuilder<AlertRecipient>().HasRequired(e => e.User)
.WithMany(e => e.AlertRecipient).HasForeignKey(e => e.UserIDInMiddleTable);
```

I've never done two many-to-many relations with one table, but I imagine with this technique it should be possible.